# Use jQuery and Dataset on ASP.NET page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to refer to a dataset or pass a dataset to jQuery function?  Here is what I am trying to do:
When user clicks in a row of a GridView control, execute a jQuery function with a parameter that specifies the row number. Then inside the jQuery function, set value(s) to a textbox based on the row of the dataset to which the GridView is bound?

Comment: The whole dataset should stored on the client via json or xml.

Comment: @deostrol Thank you.  I will study on how to pass the dataset to jQuery function via json.